# Git repo changed, updated git config, but now Android Studio does not see the repository?

Tags: android, git, android-studio

We had to change the name of Bitbucket git repository. So when I loaded the project, `Changes` tab only had `Local` part.

I then edited `.git/config` file and update the `url` inside `remote "origin"` and restarted Android Studio.

But even then, Android Studio could not see the repository with a new url. And we only changed the URL.

Did anyone ever meet anything like this? Any idea how to fix it?

Funny thing, when I delete the complete project and re-clone it, Android Studio still does not see it. So I guess the error must be inside `.idea` directory, but I am not sure what file to edit inside this directory.